# Converting from MySQL to MySQLi, how can I pass a connection to MySQLi inside of a function?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm pretty new to PHP, and I'm following this [PHP academy tutorial on a register-login system.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Til3oVNlho4&list=PLE134D877783367C7)

In the tutorial, he uses MySQL functions, like `mysql_connect`, `mysql_query`, and `mysql_real_escape_string` etc.

As recommended, I'm working on a new project and want to use mysqli to accomplish the same user login system.  I have two functions so far that require some database connectivity.   Below is the example of my sanitize function:

```
<?php
include ('connect.php');

function sanitize($data){
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($data);
}
?>
```

When I try to run this, I'll get an error like below:

> **Warning:** mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

So, I can add the connection to my function like this:

```
<?php
//include ('connect.php');

function sanitize($data){
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'array-test');
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $data);
}
?>
```

Which works successfully!  The problem is, rather than being able to pass my database connection from an include, I have to place it in the function manually.  I will have multiple functions using database connectivity, and if I'm repeating myself this much, I must be doing something wrong.

So far, the only other workaround I have thought of is passing the connection variable in an argument when I call the function.  Kind of like below:

```
<?php
include ('connect.php');

function sanitize($connection, $data){
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $data);
}
?>
```

Am I missing something?  How can I avoid manually adding the connection variable to each function I create?

Comment: You could use `global $connection`. But this means that you always have to use the same variable name for your connection.

Comment: Yes, apparently. You are missing search feature of this site, where this very question has been asked dozens times already.

Comment: Not to mention that whole your "sanitize" function is wrong and injection prone.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - No need to get snippy.  I did read over a few of the articles, but they use an OOP approach I'm not familiar with.  Since MySQLi supports both OOP and procedural styles, I thought I wouldn't hurt to ask about doing it this way.  Also, your comment on the sanitize function, while probably accurate, wasn't particularly helpful.

Comment: these questions are listed at the right side of this very page. and not all of them use OOP. There is even one from some poor fella who is learning PHP via the same ignorant "phpacademy" course. It require no special skills in programming to find it, with exactly the same answer you got here.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a global variable.

```
function sanitize($data){
    global $connection;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $data);
}
```

But it's better to just change your code so you pass the connection as a parameter. This will allow you to use multiple connections if necessary.

Comment: Such a function should never be.

Comment: Thanks I think that's what I'll end up doing.  I appreciate your help, especially since it seems other users are more interested in downvotes than helping out.